# How to derive the posterior predictive distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

I often seen the posterior predictive distribution mentioned in the context of machine learning and bayesian inference. The definition is as follows:

$ p(D'|D) = \int_\theta p(D'|\theta)p(\theta|D)$

How/why does the integral on the right equal the probability distribution on the left? In other words, which laws of probability can I use to derive $p(D'|D)$ given the integral?

**Edit** - After further consideration, I think I am able to see much of the derivation. That is,

$p(D'|D) = \int_\theta p(D', \theta | D)$ via the law of total probability
$p(D'|D) = \int_\theta p(D' | D, \theta) * p(\theta | D)$  via the chain rule

But I don't understand why $D$ may be dropped from the list of conditioned variables belonging to the integral's first term.

Comment: This definitely isn't a bad place to ask this. But also you may find http://stats.stackexchange.com/ to be a good place. They deal with a lot of machine learning as well as general statistics and probability theory there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it frowned upon to cross-post to both boards?

Comment: Generally yes, you want to have one question on one site, but in the event that it doesn't get enough activity here say in a week, it wouldn't be a bad idea to post there. In the meantime any researching, digging at articles, trying to make sense of some guide, that you do wouldn't also be bad to post here. You might get very close and only need the smallest "hint"

Comment: I'd say cross-posting should happen only infrequently (although I agree with @frogeyedpeas that this question is good for both forums).  However, in any event you should definitely mention in each that you have cross-posted and update both when you get an answer.

Comment: As a follow up, I found later that this is clearly explained in a lecture on Bayesian methods at the University of Edinburgh. The video can be found [here](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/vision/VIDEO/2015/mlpr.htm) and the explanation takes place about 8 minutes through the "Bayesian methods" video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p(D',\theta | D) = p(D' | \theta,D)p(\theta | D)$ is from Bayes rules, provided we have densities:

$p(D',\theta | D) = \frac{P(D', \theta, D)}{P(D)} = \frac{P(D'|\theta, D) P(\theta, D)}{P(D)} = P(D'|\theta, D) P(\theta | D)$.

Now integrate out the nuisance variable $\theta$ on both sides. Your formula also appears to have a Markov-type assumption $p(D'|\theta,D)=p(D'|\theta)$.

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by "Markov-type assumption?"

Comment: That's the assumption that $D'$ is independent of $D$ conditional on $\theta$, equivalent to the formula that I wrote above. This is characteristic of Markov processes but my referring to it as a Markov assumption rather than conditional independence may be completely misleading in your context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have the same question reading *Bayesian data analysis (Gelman A., Carlin J.B.)*, which is the equation 1.4

Answer (score 4):

To show this one can follow a somewhat standard argument. In what follows, for notational convenience, I have replaced your "$D$"s with "$S$"s. By the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) (in terms of conditional expectation) and [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), applied to any bounded measurable function $f$ defined on the relevant sample space $\Omega$, we observe that
$$
\eqalign{
\int_{\Omega}f(s^{'})p(s^{'}\mid s)\mathrm ds^{'}&=\mathbb E[f(S^{'})\mid S=s]=\mathbb  E[E[f(S^{'})\mid \Theta\,,s]\mid S=s]\\&=\int_{\theta}\left(\int_{\Omega}f(s^{'})p(s^{'}\mid \theta\,,s) \mathrm ds^{'}\right)p(\theta\mid s)\mathrm d\theta \\&= \int_{\Omega}f(s^{'})\left(\int_{\theta}p(s^{'}\mid \theta\,,s)p(\theta\mid s)\mathrm d\theta\right) \mathrm ds^{'}} 
$$

Since the far l.h.s. is equal to the far r.h.s. for all bounded measurable functions, we conclude that 
$$
p(s^{'}\mid s)=\int_{\theta}p(s^{'}\mid \theta\,,s)p(\theta\mid s)\mathrm d\theta
$$

Comment: Can you explain why "$\mathbb E[f(S^{'})\mid S=s]=\mathbb  E[E[f(S^{'})\mid \Theta\,,s]\mid S=s]$"? Is it not $\mathbb E[f(S^{'})\mid S]=\mathbb  E[E[f(S^{'})\mid \Theta\,,S]\mid \Theta]$?

Comment: I mean by $E(X)=E(E(X|Y))$, is it just let $X=s'|s$, then $E(s'|s)=E(E((s'|s)|Y))$?